# TCP & Wireshark - Server not re-transmitting segments?

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, wireshark

I am new to TCP-in-depth-analysis which I need for a current problem.

## Connections:

- **Client = Host PC, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (IP: ...60)**
- Switch (TL-SG1016D by tp-link, Gbit)
- **Server = Proprietary embedded device (IP: ...61)** (let's call it **ED**). There's a BeagleBone Green V1.1 in that ED. As far as I know there's no OS running on it. All embedded programming, highly time-critical procedures.
- Wireshark running on client side, capturing on server side not possible.
- Switch is connected to the rest of our IT-network

## Software:

- Vendor of ED provides API for communication PC<->ED. For me as a user access to TCP-stack is hidden.
- I have an own software running on the Host PC does various procedures on the ED. In this case it is polling some data, cycle time 150msec. Each polling frame has a segment size of 3 Bytes, each answer has a size of 49 Bytes.

## The problem:

- At some point once in a while the ED does not react anymore. A can call any API-function and it doesn't do anything.
- Calling the API-functions returns "all ok", no error/timeout/whatsoever. The doc to the API shows that there are return values for "no connection" or "error on transmission" which I can actually provoke by unplugging the cable during communication initialisation of the ED. (But there I don't call those functions that I use in the Wireshark log)

## My analysis via Wireshark and questions in bold:

- In general there's not a lot of traffic going on on that port.
- RTT is very low: less than 1msec.
- After error I can still ping the ED, but that's ICMP not TCP, right? So not relevant I guess.
- Wireshark shows that the moment of that moment where the ED freezes is exactly the moment where there's something not normal going on on the TCP-level:

  - Frame 19: last frame of regular communication. But there is no answer comming in.
  - Frame 21: next regular data request according to my polling cycle.
  - Frame 22: answer from the ED: Sequence number shows that exactly 1 paket seems to have been lost (with sequ. 148). It acks both of those last requests. Fine. This can happen.
  - Frame 23: Host sends ACK to that, but with last ACK (No SACK info in frame). So Wireshark tags this as "Dup ACK". I'm still fine with that.
  - And this is how it goes on. The ED acks all incoming request and answers them correctly. **Question 1: But shouldn't there be a retransmission of the outstanding paket? Is this a violation of the RFC9293?** There's enough time for that I would think.
  - Then, from frame 92 on the ED changes its answerts to "zero content" ... ok that's probably not a TCP issue. But: **Question 2: Why are those few following ACKS not tagged as "DUP ACKs"?**
  - And then the communication stops completely. I guess that's something in the API because my software keeps polling. **Question 3: Is this still proper TCP (meaning: connection still established but simply no traffic) or should there be FINs etc.?**

### Log screenshots:

[Log page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rm1W.png)
[Log page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjoNs.png)

Comment: `Calling the API-functions returns "all ok", no error/timeout` what basis do you have that this should be localized to a network issue? An "API" that returns "ok" when it is expected to return something else like data is not network, even with a low quality unmanaged switch like a TP Link TL-SG1016D.

Comment: @GregAskew See my edit above.