# TCP & Wireshark: Retransmission not working?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I traced a TCP connection in wireshark and try to understand how ACK'ing should work correctly.

As you can see in the picture at some point there's a paket missing from IPx.61. Wireshark tags this with "previous segment not captured".
Then the usual traffic goes on, but pakets from IPx.60 don't change their ACK number = The client demands the missing paket. It does this for 15 times.
Next, IPx.61 starts sending empty ACK-Frames and soon after IPx.60 doesn't send anything anymore.
I have traced the traffic for some more days (!) after that but **the lost paket is not sent / retransmitted again by IPx.61. Shouldn't it have be retransmitted quite immediately after this? Is this maybe an incorrected implemented TCP-stack on device IPx.61? Or am I misunderstanding something?**

(This question is part of this question: [TCP & Wireshark - Server not re-transmitting segments?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1155836/tcp-wireshark-server-not-re-transmitting-segments))[image]